# Why isn't there a way to infer a formula from market data?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Looking the graphic of a stock, one could intuitively guess a mathematician could infer a formula that fit the graphic and, from that, get future values.

Is that possible, to some extent, and what are the limitations?

Comment: There is no future. The future does not exist. Not even weather forecasts are always accurate.

Comment: If an extrapolation (even a short one) would work with probability 100%, this would be a way to become rich without any risk.

Answer (score 1):

Given a data set or a graphic comming from experiments and/or measurements, the difficulty is not to find a formula that provides an expected fitting. In fact, on the theoretical viewpoint, there are an infinity of convenient formulas. The difficulty is to find which formula among them is the true one.

If such a formula is used to extapolation (guessing future values for example) only the true one can give reliable information. The other ones will leads to more or less deviations in the results.

For example see :
http://mathhelpforum.com/advanced-applied-math/224263-fourier-transform-question-fitting-data-sine-like-curve.html
where several functions are very well fitted to a given data set and many other could be found as well.

Comment: Is there a name for that I'm looking for?

Comment: Interpolation (for past values), or extrapolation (for future values).

Comment: Or "curve fitting" or "data fitting".

Comment: +1 for the infinity of convenient formulae, which are all approximating an incredibly complex and unpredictable system

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully reading what you are requesting.
I have always used Excel on my data ( sales/inventories, etc). Excel can provide a polynomial regression up to 6th order. I find it helpful because the coefficients and the R² values tell me more likely what the underlying polynomial is.
It can also do Power Series and exponential, and if you go back to the Sum-of-the-Squares, you could essentially concoct a regression.
My understanding is that the polynomial functions are the ad-hoc granddads of the other regressions (* a la Taylor), so they should help.  Chi² is supposed to predict a best-fit probability distribution, which might help.
The issue with Fourier in this case IMHO, is that is portends a fundamental harmonic, and that value and its 'overtones' might be riddled with spurious datums, since marketing data is not necessarily harmonic.